# make background white in scanned pdf?

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf file of a scanned document that contains some gray boxes that makes text pretty much unreadable when printed.
How can I lighten the color of these boxes to make it negligible ?
Here's an example :
[image]

Comment: Are you asking after you scan it or during the scan? After scan you would need third party photo editing software to do what you want.

Comment: @Moab after. What can I use and how? I have acrobat pro at my disposal btw (if it can help?)

Comment: Your question belongs on this site......https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/      I'll ask to move it

Answer (score 2):

After scanning, it is possible to improve the inmage somewhat using tools such as [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/). Below, the contrast has been increased:

[image: IrfanView increased contrast correction]

A *much* more effective way to adjust the image is with the scanner utility tools, *before* saving to file, as below:

[image: Advance scan tools]

Since the background appears to be dots, i.e. a [halftone image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone), you could try *Descreening*, *Remove Background* and/or *Text Enhancement* switches, and adjust *Contrast*, *Brightness* and *Gamma* while you observe the impact on the image before saving it.

Of course, the scanner settings available depend on your scanner and drivers, but there should be *some* adjustments available.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [pdfsandwich](http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich/index.html) which is a convenient wrapper that can call [unpaper](https://www.flameeyes.com/projects/unpaper) on all of the pages (and ocr at the same time.)

e.g.,

```
pdfsandwich --layout single inputfile.pdf
```

will trim black borders, remove "half-columns" from the facing page, whiten the background, and deskew/resize/center the text columns.